# Jenkins multi string parameter printing strings in single line

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create on freestyle project with multi string parameter. This will be built by user  he have to input string values. Those strings will be embedded to file and pushed to s3 bucket. But the problem is whenever user trying to input multiple strings all the values are coming in single line.

user input

```
a
b
c
```

expected output:

```
a 
b
c
```

Actual output i am getting
`a b c`

Comment: how about adding "<br>"  when u print the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sample parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVsfy.png)

I guess i figured it out.

printf '%s\n' "$tables_retained" > textfile1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below while assigning multi-line value to a string:-

```
def a = """\
         test
         test
         test""".stripIndent()
println(a);
```